# Need to create multiple fields that aggregate the data

Tags: sql, oracle

Need to aggregate the data multiple times (too many times) how can I achieve this without inserting the inner select statement for each aggregation. Don't want to do a union as the query will become too big, would rather do it the way I have shown below but not sure what to put in the from clause I don't want to insert in there the inner select clause as below is just a example the real inner select statement I am working with is 10x bigger.
For example

```
select (
  select count(id)
  from ?
  where date_1 = 2022
  and date_2 = 2021
)
(
  select sum(sales)
  from ?
  where date_1 = 2020
  and date_2 = 2018
)
(
  select sum(profit)
  from ?
  where date_1 = 2020
  and date_2 = 2021
)
from (
  select id,
  profit,
  sales,
  date 1,
  date_2
  from orders_table
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation; something like:

```
select count(case when date_1 = 2022 and date_2 = 2021 then id end),
  sum(case when date_1 = 2020 and date_2 = 2018 then sales else 0 end),
  sum(case when date_1 = 2020 and date_2 = 2021 then profit else 0 end)
from orders_table
```

or if sales/profit can be null, use nvl or coalesce so the sum doesn't end up null:

```
select count(case when date_1 = 2022 and date_2 = 2021 then id end),
  sum(coalesce(case when date_1 = 2020 and date_2 = 2018 then sales end, 0)),
  sum(coalesce(case when date_1 = 2020 and date_2 = 2021 then profit end, 0))
from orders_table
```

The `count()` function only counts non-null values; the case expression only evaluates to a non-null value when the years conditions are matched, so it only counts those matching IDs.

The `sum()` function will return null if any value is null, so for that you either need to have `else 0` to give a nominal value for the non-matching rows, or coalesce to zero so non-matching rows - and any potential null matching values - don't cause the whole sum to be null.

---

You could also change your 'inner select clause' from an inline view (which you'd be trying to reference too many levels down) to a common table expression (CTE):

```
with cte as (
  select id,
  profit,
  sales,
  date_1,
  date_2
  from orders_table
)
select (
  select count(id)
  from cte
  where date_1 = 2022
  and date_2 = 2021
),
(
  select sum(sales)
  from cte
  where date_1 = 2020
  and date_2 = 2018
),
(
  select sum(profit)
  from cte
  where date_1 = 2020
  and date_2 = 2021
)
from dual
```

but conditional aggregation (or pivoting depending on what you need) is probably going to be simpler and easier to maintain than multiple subqueries.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=7e1d94fb961206bc95b9ed59bb542713) with some very dummy data.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the helpful answers going to use the conditional aggregation way as it is the easiest way to use with my current query

Answer (score 1):

If you want your output as columns (rather than rows) then you can use a `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT id,
       sales,
       profit_22_21,
       profit_20_18,
       profit_20_21
FROM   orders_table
PIVOT (
  SUM(profit)
  FOR (date_1, date_2) IN (
    (2022, 2021) AS profit_22_21,
    (2020, 2018) AS profit_20_18,
    (2020, 2021) AS profit_20_21
  )
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE orders_table (id, sales, date_1, date_2, profit) AS
SELECT 1, 'X', 2022, 2021, 10 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'X', 2020, 2018, 10 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  7 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'X', 2020, 2021, 10 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  3 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Y', 2022, 2021, 10 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Y', 2020, 2018, 10 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  2 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Z', 2020, 2021, 10 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  4 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'X', 2022, 2021, 10 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  6 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'X', 2020, 2018, 10 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  8 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'X', 2020, 2021, 10 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  9;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | SALES | PROFIT_22_21 | PROFIT_20_18 | PROFIT_20_21 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2 | X | 60 | 80 | 90 |
> | 1 | Y | 10 | 20 | *null* |
> | 1 | Z | *null* | *null* | 40 |
> | 1 | X | 100 | 70 | 30 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bcf4a74d87a9c66ba21ee3080c0782c4)*

Answer (score 1):

Aggregation functions return only row, but you can use `CASE WHEN THEN` to select the data you want

> ```
> CREATE TABLE orders_table 
> (id int, profit DECIMAL(10,2), sales DECIMAL(10,2),date_1 date, date_2 date)
> ```

> ```
> select 
>   count(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_1) = 2022
>   and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_2) = 2021 THEN id END),
>
>
>
>   sum(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_1) = 2019
>   and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_2) = 2018 THEN sales END ),
>   
>
>   sum(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_1) = 2010
>   and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_2) = 2021 THEN  profit END)
>
> from (
>   select id,
>   profit,
>   sales,
>   date_1,
>   date_2
>   from orders_table
> ) t1
> ```
>
> ```
> COUNT(CASEWHENEXTRACT(YEARFROMDATE_1)=2022ANDEXTRACT(YEARFROMDATE_2)=2021THENIDEND) | SUM(CASEWHENEXTRACT(YEARFROMDATE_1)=2019ANDEXTRACT(YEARFROMDATE_2)=2018THENSALESEND) | SUM(CASEWHENEXTRACT(YEARFROMDATE_1)=2010ANDEXTRACT(YEARFROMDATE_2)=2021THENPROFITEND)
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------: | -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------: | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------:
>                                                                                   0 |                                                                                 null |                                                                                  null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0bd700650c5df4128c6f4da265325fc7)*